# Remap the language-toggling key mapping in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following settings in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=0
highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Red
```

By default, I can toggle the input language with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. However, I find the mapping inconvenient.
Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! One can always create a custom mapping.
To remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>
to, say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, use:

```
:lnoremap <c-l> <c-^>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but after adding line to `.vimrc` this doesn't work for me in insert mode (after pressing `Ctrl+l` I get `^L` in vi, after change to `inoremap <c-l> <c-^>` (`i` for `insert`) all works like expected.

Comment: @Sonique: It should have been the `:lnoremap` command instead. (The answer is updated accordingly now.) The `:noremap` command creates mappings for Normal, Visual, and Operator-pending modes, while the purposes of this shortcut are best suited with a language mapping, which works in Insert and Command-line modes as well as in other text-input contexts like entering a search pattern. See `:help language-mapping` for details.